# Visual Studio 2013 Build Failed, MSB4061

Tags: visual-studio

When I build my project using Visual Studio 2013, found several errors and report MSB 4061

[image]

Could you help to fix this build errors?

Comment: Please paste in the actual text, not a picture.

Comment: I would use "depends" to find the missing dependency for the DLL "intel.misc.utilities.dll".

Comment: If `intel.misc.utilities.dll` is not required remove it from project otherwise you need to recover this file back.